Steps to Use AWS Data Exchange as a Provider with Python and S3
I am looking for guidance on how to use the AWS Data Exchange service as a provider, specifically using Python and S3. I would appreciate a detailed explanation of the steps involved, as well as information on the required the structure of the data, which is in JSON format.
Any examples or documentation references would be helpful.
Thank you!
I am using boto3 and S3 to manage JSON data files

My Owned data sets - status are showing 'ready to share' under 'My Data (AWS-DataExchange)'. I want know the next steps. Thanks
